# terraform and references in local-exec DESTROY provisioners

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

i am trying to manage database users along with the database for an azure instance, and this is surprisingly … impossible. I thought I found a way using a local-exec provider, but … well, apparently not. the code and the error message are below.

it boils down to terraform complaining that I reference non-static stuff from other resources, which I just … don’t. I only use static parameters, nothing else. what I don’t understand is that I can reference variables even in provider configs - but for destroy provisioners it’s too dynamic?

appreciate any help!

and on to the code … :

```
resource "azurerm_postgresql_database" "db" {
  server_name         = var.server_name
  resource_group_name = var.server_rg
  name                = var.db_name
  charset             = var.db_charset
  collation           = var.db_collation


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${path.module}/mgt-user.sh create '${var.server_fqdn}' '${var.server_admin_user}' '${var.db_name}' '${var.db_user_pass}'"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "${path.module}/mgt-user.sh destroy '${var.server_fqdn}' '${var.server_admin_user}' '${var.db_name}' '${var.db_user_pass}'"
  }
}
```

now when I run terraform init i get this:

```
Error: Invalid reference from destroy provisioner

  on ../modules/dbs/pg-db-and-user/db_and_user.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_postgresql_database" "db":
  27:     command = "echo ${path.module}/create_user.sh destroy '${var.server_fqdn}' '${var.server_admin_user}' '${var.db_name}' '${var.db_user_pass}'"

Destroy-time provisioners and their connection configurations may only
reference attributes of the related resource, via 'self', 'count.index', or
'each.key'.

References to other resources during the destroy phase can cause dependency
cycles and interact poorly with create_before_destroy.
```

Comment: If this is accurate, then you probably need to file an issue on the tracker so the logic can be refined.

Comment: I just tried with `0.12.20` terraform version, `terraform init` worked. It would be good if you can add the vars file too.

Comment: So, now I understand the problem here. It's the `${path.module}` value being passed in the destroy provisioner. If you use some other static path like `/tmp`, `/home` it works with a warning. 

This has been discussed here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23675 and a wider discussion here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23679

Answer (score 10):

#### Update

The below answer doesn't work. One way of doing is with `null_resource` with `local-exec` & `triggers`. An example is like ::

```
resource "null_resource" "delete_venafi_cert" {

triggers = {
    venafi_url      = var.venafi_url
    cert_name       = var.cert_name
    venafi_scope    = var.venafi_delete_scope
    venafi_client   = var.venafi_client_id
    venafi_oath_url = var.venafi_oauth_url
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when       = destroy
    command    = "${path.module}/delete-venafi-certificate.sh ${self.triggers.venafi_url} ${self.triggers.cert_name} ${self.triggers.venafi_scope} ${self.triggers.venafi_client} ${self.triggers.venafi_oath_url}"
    on_failure = continue
  }
}
```

#### BELOW ONE DOESN'T WORK

The below snippet must work with a warning rather than throwing an error. The problem was because of `path.module` variable being used in tandem with `destroy` provisioner.

Terraform says this will be improved in further releases. Until then, you could pass `working_dir` pointing to `path.module` var.

```
resource "azurerm_postgresql_database" "db" {
  server_name         = var.server_name
  resource_group_name = var.server_rg
  name                = var.db_name
  charset             = var.db_charset
  collation           = var.db_collation


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${path.module}/mgt-user.sh create '${var.server_fqdn}' '${var.server_admin_user}' '${var.db_name}' '${var.db_user_pass}'"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "./mgt-user.sh destroy '${var.server_fqdn}' '${var.server_admin_user}' '${var.db_name}' '${var.db_user_pass}'"
    working_dir = path.module
  }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to below links::

- [Allow destroy-time provisioners to access variables](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23679)
- [permit destroy-time local-exec provisioner to reference path.module](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23675)

Comment: Does your solution actually work? I still get the error because I have ${var.env} in my command

Comment: I've not tested this with recent versions of terraform. I don't like these create/destroy provisioners. Avoid them at all costs as they break testability. 
In unavoidable scenarios, you can use the `self.*` variables as part of the `resource`.